# Does new APNs certificate require release?

Tags: iphone, ios5, app-store, apple-push-notifications

It's time to upgrade our production APNs certificate.  I'm aware of how to do this through the provisioning portal, but I can't find any documentation indicating whether doing so requires us to release a freshly signed app.  I don't believe it does, but I can't find any hard evidence to back that up.

Can anyone point to relevant documentation?  If not, have you had success with updating your cert without releasing an updated app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that no, you do not need to release an updated app.  We were diagnosing some issues that immediately followed upgrading our certificate, so I was looking into this as an issue.  Turned out to be something unrelated, so I can vouch that you do not need to push an update.